# How do I use the RUST modules?

Tags: rust

I want to use the structure of model's rodo.rs in controller's todo.rs.
How should I write the mod?

```
use actix_web::{get, post, web, HttpResponse,Responder};
mod model;
#[get("/todos/{id}")]
pub async fn get_todo(web::Path(id): web::Path<u32>) -> impl Responder {
    println!("get_todo");
    let id_option: Option<u32> = Some(id);
    HttpResponse::Ok().json(model::Todo {
        id: id_option,
        content: String::from("やること"),
        completed: false,
    })
}

#[post("/todos")]
pub async fn post_todo(todo: web::Json<model::Todo>) -> impl Responder {
    println!("post_todo");
    println!("{:?}", todo);
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("ok")
}
```

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Todo {
    id: Option<u32>,
    content: String,
    completed: bool,
}
```

[image]

I want to use the structure of model's rodo.rs in controller's todo.rs.
How should I write the mod?
How else can I use the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose a slightly different structure[image]

```
//src/main.rs
mod app
```

```
//src/app.rs
pub mod controller;
pub mod model;
pub mod repository ... etc
```

```
//src/app/controller.rs
pub mod user;
 ... etc
```

```
//src/app/controller/user.rs //implementation controller
```

```
//src/app/repository.rs
pub mod user;
.. etc
```

```
//src/app/repository/user.rs //implementation repository
```

Answer (score 1):

The way your files are layed out you'd have to add the following `mod` declarations and `use` statements to the files:

```rust
//src/main.rs
pub mod controller;
pub mod model;
```

```rust
// src/controller.rs
pub mod todo;
```

```rust
// src/model.rs
pub mod todo;
```

```rust
// src/controller/todo.rs
use crate::model::todo::*; // * to include everything from src/model/todo.rs which i guess you'll need
```